# How can I locate program files?

Tags: wine, installed-programs

How can I locate program files for apps installed using Wine  on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: they are located on your `./wine` directory on `home`.

Answer (score 2):

The `Program Files` directory for `wine` is in `~/.wine/drive_c`. The `ProgramData`, `users` 
and `windows` folders that you are used to in windows are also located in `~/.wine`

Comment: Thank you so much. I can now locate them